# What is the purpose of saving data to NSUserDefaults since plist file in my computer?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

When I save something like an array to NSUserDefaults plist, I see the plist file in my computer not in app itself. So if I submit my app to App Store, user could reach my plist?

```
if let items = defaults.array(forKey: "ToDoListArray") as? [String]{
    itemArray = items
}
```

Above, my array (forKey: "ToDoListArray") saved to plist. Is there a way to change plist directory into app? How do you guys use local data in real scenario (Assuming that the app is in the App Store).

Comment: Presumably you are seeing the file on your computer because you are running on the simulator. When an app runs on a real device, the file is stored in the application sandbox on that device. I would suggest, however, that something like a todo list should be in Core Data, not user defaults

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand this now. I am creating a todo list app now and trying to understand if I use firrbase or stored file in user phone. I am asking this what if user reset phone and file will be reset also and user wont see privious datas. What would you recommend me as a beginner developer? Database or stored data.

Comment: It is up to you. If you want to make data available in the cloud and on multiple devices then you can use Firebase. This is more complex that just local storage. If the user backs up their device then they can restore the local storage after they reset their phone.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults are used to store app specific user data in the system. This allows to restore state or persist settings for your application. These user defaults are not made to be shipped with your application. They are purely a local storage medium for said data.

If you want to have default user defaults you have to set them on application start up, when no other values are found (or the found values are invalid).

Comment: you mean I have to use this for like Status Bar Style in the build and I do not use this for like database?

Comment: What I mean are application settings or UI state informations. If a status bar style is part of your application state (and you change that style depending on some condition or user preference) then yes, this is what should be stored there. Not sure where a database comes into play here.

Comment: `UserDefaults` is intended for very small user options like on-off switch settings. If you're storing more than a couple of dozen individual values across your entire app, you are doing it wrong. It should NEVER be used to store a whole database.

Comment: Tell this the OP :-). The question is terrible and easy to misunderstood. It should rather be something like: "Where to store my application data?" and yes CoreData is the answer for that, as Paulw11 alredy pointed out.